# The branching chain

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Let $X_{nk}$ a sequence of  i.i.d random variables, , on some suitable probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$, taking positive integer values. Define the Galton-Watson as the sequence of random variables $Z_n$ defined by $Z_n=\sum_{k=1}^{Z_{n-1}}X_{nk}$, where $Z_0=1$.

I want to proof that
$$
\mathbb{P}[Z_n=j|Z_0=1, Z_1=i_1,\ldots,Z_n=i]=\mathbb{P}[Z_n=j|Z_{n-1}=i]=\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{k=1}^i X_{nk}=j \right).
$$
In other words, $(Z_n)$ is a Markov Chain.

Why can I just replace $Z_{n-1}$ by $i$ in the explicit expression of $Z_n$?

Here is my problem, I can see intuitively  that $Z_n$ depends only on $Z_{n-1}$.  However I'm no being able to rigorously justify the above equalities, in terms of conditional probabilities, or conditional expectation properties. So  I'm asking for some help.

Comment: What are the $X_k$'s?

Comment: $X_k^{'s}$ are a sequence of iid random variables, taking positive integer values

Comment: I think you cannot do that last simplification step. Suppose the $X_k$'s take values in $\{ 1,2 \}$. Now look at $P(Z_2=3 \mid Z_1=2)$. This is not just $P(X_1+X_2=3)$, because the condition forces $X_1=2$.

Comment: For a Galton-Watson process, your equation for $\ Z_{n+1}\ $ needs to be of the form
$$
Z_{n+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{Z_n}X_{k{\color{red}n}}\ .
$$
That is, the random variables in each sum must be *different* ones from those in any other.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera  I'am assuming that they are all i.i.d

Comment: That misses the point.  If $\  Z_n=\sum_\limits{i=1}^{Z_{n-1}}X_i\ $ for all $\ n\ $, then
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\big(Z_{n+1}=Z_{m+1}\,|Z_n=Z_m\big)&=\mathbb{P}\left(\left.\sum_\limits{i=1}^{Z_n}X_i=\sum_\limits{i=1}^{Z_m}X_i\,\right|Z_n=Z_m\right)\\
&=1\ ,
\end{align}
and then $\ \mathbb{P}\left(\left.\bigcap_\limits{t=0}^\infty \{Z_{n+t}=Z_{m+t}\}\,\right|Z_n=Z_m\right)=1\ $ by induction. That is certainly *not* true in general for a Galton-Watson process.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera, you seem to be correct, however  even with this correction I can't see how to show that $(Z_n)$ is a Markov process

Answer (score 1):

Note that
\begin{align}
\big\{\,Z_0=1,Z_1=i_1,\dots,Z_r=i_r\,\big\}&=\left\{Z_0=1,X_{11}=i_1,\sum_{i=1}^{i_1}X_{2i}=i_2, \dots,\sum_{i=1}^{i_{r-1}}X_{ri}=i_r\right\}\ .
\end{align}
Therefore
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\big(Z_0=1,Z_1=i_1,\dots,Z_r=i_r\big)&=\prod_{t=1}^r\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{i_{t-1}}X_{ti}=i_t\right)
\end{align}
by the independence of $\ X_{ti}\ $ (where $\ i_0=1\ $).  It follows that
\begin{align}
(1)\hspace{6em}\mathbb{P}\big(Z_n=i_n\ \big|\,&Z_0=1,Z_1=i_1,\dots,Z_{n-1}=i_{n-1}\big)\\
&=\frac{\prod_\limits{t=1}^n\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_\limits{i=1}^{i_{t-1}}X_{ti}=i_t\right)}{\prod_\limits{t=1}^{n-1}\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_\limits{i=1}^{i_{t-1}}X_{ti}=i_t\right)}\\
&=\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_\limits{i=1}^{i_{n-1}}X_{ni}=i_n\right)\ .
\end{align}
But\begin{align}
(2)\hspace{2em}\mathbb{P}\big(Z_n=i_n\,\big|\,Z_{n-1}=i_{n-1}\,\big)&=\frac{\mathbb{P}\big(Z_n=i_n, Z_{n-1}=i_{n-1}\,\big)}{\mathbb{P}\big(Z_{n-1}=i_{n-1}\,\big)}\\
&=\frac{\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_\limits{i=1}^{i_{n-1}}X_{ni}=i_n,Z_{n-1}=i_{n-1} \right)} {\mathbb{P}\big(Z_{n-1}=i_{n-1}\,\big)}\\
&=\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_\limits{i=1}^{i_{n-1}}X_{ni}=i_n\right)\ ,
\end{align}
because $\ Z_{n-1}\ $ is a function of $\ X_{tj}\ $ for $\ t\le n-1\ $ and therefore $\ Z_{n-1}, X_{n1}, X_{n2},\dots,X_{ni_{n-1}}\ $ are independent random variables.  The identity
$$
\mathbb{P}\big(Z_n=i_n\ \big|\,Z_0=1,Z_1=i_1,\dots,Z_{n-1}=i_{n-1}\big)= \mathbb{P}\big(Z_n=i_n\,\big|\,Z_{n-1}=i_{n-1}\,\big)
$$
now follows from $(1)$ and $(2)$.